# Adding colored highlights in fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator

New to illustrator.

I'm trying to add highlights to a image I'm trying to digitize. The image looks like below

[image: Sample image]
[image: Digital Image]

I'd love to be able to replicate the white "rough" coloring approach. Is there an easy way to do this in illustrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the green object is a single closed path with a green fill and black stroke, you could Expand the stroke and fill, ungroup it, select the green fill, then use the Knife tool to cut it into pieces, then select the highlight piece, then fill it with the colour you want.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this in vector. You could either draw the white highlight shapes on top, and make it with a white fill and no border, or you could copy and paste on the same place the green body, separating the fill and border, and change the fill-only shape to match the original highlight.

Comment: I would say... it is super easy to do this in vector.